# Let $g(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\not=0$ and $g(0)=0$. Show that $g^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $g(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\not=0$ and $g(0)=0$. Show that $g^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

In the text it is already proven that for the function $f$ with $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$, we have $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.

This is what we thought:
As $g(x)=f(x^2)$ for $x\in\Bbb R$, we may be able to use this. As $g^{(n)}$ becomes very hairy after taking a couple of derivatives. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Prove recursively the stronger property that for every $n\geqslant0$ there exists a polynomial $P_n$ such that $g^{(n)}(x)=P_n(1/x)\,\mathrm e^{-1/x^2}$ for every $x\ne0$ and $g^{(n)}(0)=0$.

The induction will use the fact (which you might want to prove) that, for every polynomial $Q$, $Q(1/x)\,\mathrm e^{-1/x^2}\to0$ when $x\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

Using induction and [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) it suffices to prove that for every $n\in\mathbb N$
$$
  \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{~~e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}~~}{x^n}
~=~
  0
$$
We can assume that $n=2k$ is even, since if the assert holds for $n$ so it does for $n-1$. Therefore, setting $t=\frac{1}{x^2}$ we have to show that
$$
  \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{~~t^n~~}{e^t}
~=~
  0
$$
Applying $n$ times L'Hôpital's rule you have
$$
  \lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{~~t^n~~}{e^t}
~=~
  \lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{~~n!~~}{e^t}
~=~
  0
$$

### EDIT

As commented by @Did the answer requires a bit more details; namely we are going to prove the following

If $h:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a function such that

- $h\in C^\infty(U_0\setminus\{0\})$, where $U_0$ is a neighborhood of $0$;
- $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x)}{x^n}=0}$ $~\forall n\geq 0$,

then $h$ has derivatives of any order in $x=0$ and $h^{(n)}(0)=0$ $\forall n$.

**Proof.** Let us first check the assert for $n=1$:
$$
  h'(0)
~=~
  \lim_{x\to 0}
  {
    \frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x}
  }
~=~
  \lim_{x\to 0}
  {
    \frac{h(x)}{x}
  }
~=~
0
$$
and the last two equalities hold for the assumptions on $h$. Now, let us use induction. Suppose $n\geq 1$ and that the claim holds for every $k\leq n$, i.e. that $h$ in $0$ has derivatives of order up to $n$, and that $h^{(k)}(0)=0~$ $\forall k=0\ldots n$. Let us consider the following limit:
$$
  \lim_{x\to 0}
  {
    \frac{h(x)}{x^{n+1}}
  }
~=~
  0
$$
Since we know it exists and that $h$ has derivatives in $x=0$ up to the $n$-th, the first assumption on $h$ makes it possible to use L'Hôpital's rule $n$ times, reducing the previous equality to
$$
  \lim_{x\to 0}
  {
    \frac{h^{(n)}(x)}{(n+1)!x}
  }
~=~
  0
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
  \lim_{x\to 0}
  {
    \frac{h^{(n)}(x)}{x}
  }
~=~
  0
$$
Keeping in mind the second equality, we have that
$$
  h^{(n+1)}(0)
~=~
  \lim_{x\to 0}
  {
    \frac{h^{(n)}(x)-h^{(n)}(0)}{x}
  }
~=~
  \lim_{x\to 0}
  {
    \frac{h^{(n)}(x)}{x}
  }
~=~
0
$$
and this completes the proof.

Comment: Why would $h(x)/x^n\to0$ for every $n$ imply that $h^{(n)}(0)=0$ for every $n$?

Comment: Suppose that $h(x)/x^n\to 0$ holds $\forall n$: then by L'Hôpital's rule
$$
0 = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h'(x)}{1} = h'(0)
$$
Then use induction: suppose that $h(x)/x^n\to 0$ implies $h^{(n)}(0)=0$. Then
$$
0 = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x)}{x^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{n+1}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h'(x)}{x^n}
$$
By induction, the $n$-th derivative of $h'(x)$ in $x=0$ (i.e. $h^{(n+1)}(0))$ is $0$.

Comment: This does not work. Try $h(x)=x^3\cos(1/x^2)$ then $h(x)/x^2\to0$ but $h''(0)$ does not even exist.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work for general $h$, only in this case, since in this case $h^{(n)}(x)=h(x)\frac{p_n(x)}{x^{3n}}$ for some polynomial $p_n$. The reason it fails for general $h$ is the L'Hopital has conditions. Specifically, you need to know that $\lim \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: @Did Once you know that the limit exists you can apply L'Hôpital's rule, and the answer does show it exists.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sure, with the argument you mention, the proof works (see my answer). Then why invoking L'Hospital?

Comment: @AndreasT Sorry but are you assuming the limit exists to apply L'H's rule to show the limit exists? Sounds horribly circular to me.

Comment: @Did: You're right, thank you. I improved the answer motivating my proof. Please make me know if anything is still unclear (or wrong).

Comment: The case $n=1$ of the induction you suggest fails for the example I provided in a comment 15 hours ago (that is, the property holds for $n=1$ but not for $n=2$ although every hypothesis you use to deduce the $n+1$ case from the $n$ case holds for $n=1$)

Comment: @Did: your examples has first order derivative but not second. Indeed from my answer it can be inferred that if $h(x)/x^k\to 0$ for $k=0\ldots n$, then $h^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0\ldots n-1$. Your examples indeed does not satisfy $h(x)/x^3\to 0$.

Comment: @Did: I added further assumptions on $h$. The $h$ you provided does not satisfy the first in the list, so L'Hôpital's rule cannot be used.

Comment: And the new-new-new version is kosher? Sure about that? All in all, what this little saga shows is that sometimes L'H's rule complicates things more than anything else.